# Display heading with following data rows

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I need to output from the grep below to show the recommended field headings and then just the row data as shown at the bottom

```
grep 'loadOfAreas' paco_smc.log|grep 'enter_recirc'
```

Which returns as follow (Example of two rows)

```
19-11:41:52.017 | ConveyorControllerV2      | DEBUG | [][CC-01726546-QUERY] enter_recirc =true: areas01Checked=[SMC-PCK-AREA-01-TUB-RECIRC-01] **loadOfAreas01/retrievals/storages//limitRetrieval/limitGoodsin/limitTotal 19/1/18//30/36/49/** areas02Checked=[SMC-PCK-AREA-01-TUB-EXIT-01] loadOfAreas02//limit 2//30/ areas03Checked=null loadOfAreas03//limit 2//0 TUgoingToExit=false usingExit02=false, usingExit03=false - com.ssp.custom.mfs.paco.conveyorV2.rule.StorageRetrievalBalanceLimitRuleJagSol.execute:242
19-11:41:53.140 | ConveyorControllerV2      | DEBUG | [][CC-01726552-QUERY] enter_recirc =true: areas01Checked=[SMC-PCK-AREA-01-TUB-RECIRC-01] **loadOfAreas01/retrievals/storages//limitRetrieval/limitGoodsin/limitTotal 19/1/18//30/36/49/** areas02Checked=[SMC-PCK-AREA-01-TUB-EXIT-01] loadOfAreas02//limit 2//30/ areas03Checked=null loadOfAreas03//limit 2//0 TUgoingToExit=false usingExit02=false, usingExit03=false - com.ssp.custom.mfs.paco.conveyorV2.rule.StorageRetrievalBalanceLimitRuleJagSol.execute:242
```

**How would I get it to just display like the following with the headings displaying once**

**loadOfAreas01/retrievals/storages//limitRetrieval/limitGoodsin/limitTotal**

19        1 18        30           36       49

19                1     18                30                36      49

etc

Comment: I have no idea how you get from your sample data to the desired result? What are those numbers? And learn to use those nice formatting buttons.

Comment: these numbers are displayed in the grep examples provided above, scroll across

Comment: Oh really? Where's the 41? Or the 40? Anyway, this should be doable with awk. Have you tried a tutorial or something?

Comment: I used fulltext search on the grey box content. I can see a 42 in the timestamps, a 5 in the `CC-01726546-QUERY`, a 36 in the `19/1/18//30/36/49` (but that seems taken by the `30 36 49`). You will have to do some more convincing than "scroll across". Please provide the text parts before and after the six numbers in both lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended tool for text processing is `awk`.
You can easily pipe your desired output to the following.

If you want to print any header, you can use the awk's `BEGIN` section.
`awk 'BEGIN{print "loadOfAreas01 retrievals storages - limitRetrieval limitGoodsin limitTotal"}'`

It seems your output have a constant format and therefore you want to have some text processing on column 12 like this.

`{t=$12; gsub(/\/\//, " - ", t); gsub(/\//, " ", t); gsub(/ \*\*/,"", t); print t}`

If you add this to the command before you can compute this:

```
your_command | awk 'BEGIN {print "loadOfAreas01 retrievals storages - limitRetrieval limitGoodsin limitTotal"} \
{t=$12; gsub(/\/\//, " - ", t); gsub(/\//, " ", t); gsub(/ \*\*/,"", t); print t}'
```

Your output will look like this:

```
loadOfAreas01 retrievals storages - limitRetrieval limitGoodsin limitTotal
19 1 18 - 30 36 49
19 1 18 - 30 36 49
```

If you need a fancy output of course you can do this with awk's `printf` statement.
But maybe you like to use the `column` command, where you can pipe your awk output.

At least you have:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "loadOfAreas01 retrievals storages - limitRetrieval limitGoodsin limitTotal"} \
{t=$12; gsub(/\/\//, " - ", t); gsub(/\//, " ", t); gsub(/ \*\*/,"", t); print t}' |\ 
column -t
```

Now your Output will look like this:

```
loadOfAreas01  retrievals  storages  -  limitRetrieval  limitGoodsin  limitTotal
19             1           18        -  30              36            49
19             1           18        -  30              36            49
```

Comment: @sbirdi You are welcome, please mark the answer as right and vote for it  to help the community.

Comment: Can I just ask one more favour, I have tried to follow you statement to add another field (customer demand) but managed to add the heading [DateTime_Stamp] for failed onto getting the data populated. How can it get to display 19-11:41 [19-11:41:52.017] on each row?